# "Thl" money abbreviation

Tags: palaeography, abbreviations

Does anybody know what this abbreviation for money represents? I think it's "800 Thl" but not sure what type of Geld that is.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given your reference to Geld I assume this is a German speaking area so my suspicion is that it's [Thaler](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thaler).

Comment: Thanks! That's very helpful and the Wiki's interesting, too. I didn't know that the "dollar" was derived from the "Thaler". 

Anyhow,  the above snippet reads something like:

Ich schreibe Euch nicht twor??? weil Geld das Ihr mir schenkte solt,
aber wann ich vor mich anfangen will, so brauche ich 800 Thl:
und das ist nach Deushers Geld 2000 Gelden 
aber nicht weiß wie viel das Ihr mir schickten wolt,
denn ich weiß Ihr habt schon weil gethan vor mich 
welche ich Euch nicht dankbar genug seie kann. 
~

Comment: $800 in 1848 dollars would be about  $30,295 in today's dollars.

Comment: I think the last line above is "... ich Euch nicht dankbar genug seyn kann" where seyn is some old spelling variant of seien (to be).